# How can i loop through These with A CASE statement?

Tags: php, mysql, case, statements

I want to write a PHP code that will loop through a dB_table row "total" in such a way that if "total"  is equal to or greater than 70, it will display A. if it is between 69 and 55 it will display B else it will display C.
I have the below lines of code but it only consider the first and last statements.

```
$sql = "SELECT total, field1, field2, field3, CASE
WHEN total >=70 THEN 'A'
WHEN total BETWEEN 69 AND 55 THEN 'B'
  ELSE 'C'
  END AS 'field4'
FROM db_table
WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name . "' OR fullname = '" . $user_name . "';";
$result_of_login_check = $this->db_connection->query($sql);
```

The above code displays 'A' from 70 and above. It neglects the middle CASE and display 'C' from 69 & below.
How can achieve my aim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the same comparison operators you had before this can utilize indexes if you have them.

```
CASE
    WHEN total >= 70 THEN 'A'
    WHEN total >= 55 AND total < 70 THEN 'B'
    ELSE 'C'
END AS field4
```

Comment: Ruddell  pls what do you mean by INDEXES I am new to php

Comment: indexes are not for php its for mysql... when you do a select and you have indexes on a column like total... it will make your query run faster.. using > and < signs can utilize indexes in MySQL if you have them.. [**SEE DOCS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: thank you. that was really helpful
I got my total value with the below code.
 $total = $field1+$field2+$field3;

Do you know how I can get my Average?

Comment: @Gentledozy well if thats how you got your total then just divide by 3 for the average `$totalAvg = ($field1+$field2+$field3) ? 3`

Comment: thank you John. I was trying it with division operator (/). it gave me a parse error

Comment: @Gentledozy sorry I meant to put in the division operator.. Try casting each field as an integer on the python side so like `int($field1)` if that's how you do it in php should work.. Also make sure you have something inside field1 echo it to see if something is in there

Comment: Did you echo the variables?

Comment: @Gentledozy awesome glad i could help! if you could mark the answer as accepted it would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: @Gentledozy what do you want it for?

Comment: you know things more than I do. as it is here, when I post a QST, you may not see it. but if I got you on fb, I will share a link to my QST.

Comment: @JonhRudell pls check this question out stackoverflow.com/questions/26303210/selecting-from-different-mysql-db-tables

Answer (score 0):

`BETWEEN 69 AND 55` won’t work because MySQL counts from 1 to infinity :)

Try to change it to `BETWEEN 55 AND 69`.